# Python method chaining in a for loop

Tags: python, method-chaining

I have a list of html tags defined as below:

```
tags = ["text1", "text2", "text3"]
```

I will need to use theses values in a method chaining as shown below:

```
soup.find("div", class_="text1").find("div", class_="text2").find("div", class_="text3").text
```

Since the list is dynamic, is there any way i can make the method chaining `find()` dynamic as well (in a for loop maybe?)

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. Hierachical structures? Otherwise, you could just loop over the tags.

Comment: Look at the CSS selectors (or XPath)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
def find_chained(soup, classes):
    for cls in classes:
        soup = soup.find("div", class_=cls)
    return soup.text
```

Should be self-explanatory: loop over each item; the tag you found is now the new "base" tag within which you want to `find` the next `div`.

Comment: And in general, this is a special case of `soup = methodcaller(name, *args)(soup)`, where `name` is always `"find"` and `args` is constructed from `"div"` and `cls`, so it can be expanded to handle arbitrary chains of method calls.

Answer (score 4):

just use `select`

```
css_class = ' '.join([f'.{cls}' for cls in tags])
soup.select(css_class).text
```

Comment: The question could be read one of two ways, with the focus on chaining methods or with the focus on selecting a nested element in an HTML document. The accepted answer goes the first way, this answer the second.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a for loop can be used. Here each iteration we replace `relevant_section` with its first child of the right class:

```
tags = ["text1", "text2", "text3"]
relevant_section = soup
for tag in tags:
    relevant_section = relevant_section.find("div", class_=tag)
relevant_text = relevant_section.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) to automate the process of replacing `soup` with the result of a call to `soup.find`:

```
from functools import reduce


classes = ["text1", "text2", "text3"]

result = reduce(lambda s, x: s.find("div", class_=x), classes, soup).text
```

or, if you like functional tomfoolery more than the lambda expression :),

```
from operator import call, methodcaller

result = reduce(call,
                [methodcaller("find", "div", class_=x) for x in classes],
                soup).text
```